# How to save sjTable as a .png image file?

Tags: html, r, dataframe, kable

I am creating the below table using the `sjPlot` package.

[image]

I would like to save this as a png image in order to preserve resolution, but I cannot seem to make it work. As I understand it, `tab_model` saves the table as an html file, so I tried using `webshot`, but can't get it to work at all. How can I do this?

```
library(sjPlot)
data(mtcars)
exlm <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars)
tableex <- tab_model(exlm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me using `webshot` (although I don't get what you mean by "preserve resolution"; png is a raster format, after all):

```r
tab_model(exlm, file="tab.html")
library(webshot)
webshot("tab.html", "tab.png")
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that the output file has no white space? When I try the above the solution, it works but the table only takes up a small portion of the file

Comment: And by "preserve resolution" I just meant save it in a format that won't get fuzzy when I copy it elsewhere. I can just take a screenshot of my viewer, but once I put that in a word doc it loses a lot of resolution when I expand it a little.

Comment: I figured it out, the key is to use `vheight` and `wvidth` in the webshot command